# Elasticsearch search for match case inside an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search in the first item of the array for a match case. example

sample data

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "comps": [
      {
        "city": "Henderson"
      },
      {
        "city": "abc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "comps": [
      {
        "city": "new york"
      },
      {
        "city": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to query city which are the first item in comps array which results in ["Henderson", "new york"]
and further i can  match case like %york% results in ["new york"]

i have tried this

```
query: {
 {
      match: { city: 'york' }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are looking for an infix, or substring match for which you need to change the way your documents are tokenized and searched. please refer [n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) which can serve your use-case, will add a working example according to your use-case.

Comment: Also note that the OP wants to search only in the first element of the array

Comment: @Val, thanks I also noticed and wanted to ask OP why is want to do so..